# Debugging OpenGL ES 2.0 game that runs in Windows through PowerVR emulation

Tags: opengl-es

I have small cross platform engine that runs my OpenGL ES 2.0 games on Android and on Windows. To run it on Windows I am using PowerVR emulator (just libraries linked to the project). It all works well.

Now I would like to debug it and inspect in any OpenGL debugger. I tried Intel GPA, AMD CodeXL, gDebugger, glslDevil. But non of them were able to do it. In case of Intel GPA it did not find the running game. In other cases it started the game but failed to pause it or do anything later.

I do not know whether it is because it is OpenGL ES instead of OpenGL. But the PowerVR emulation must work like translating OpenGL ES to OpenGL, I think?

My questions are:

- Is there any (utility) way how to debug OpenGL ES 2.0 programs on Windows?
- Or is there any better emulation library than PowerVR that will force the app look like OpenGL for other tools (instead of OpenGL ES)?

I am doing all this as none of debuggers work for me on Android device. I am developing with Samsung Galaxy Tab (which is Tegra GPU), but Nvida's PerfHUD ES does not currently support it (and I also do not meet Android 4.0 or higher having only 3.1)

- Is there any way how to debug OpenGL ES on Android device that has Android version 3.1 and it is Samsung Galaxy Tab device?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - PVRVFrame translates OpenGL ES calls into host OpenGL calls. This is why the likes of gDEBugger will capture the OpenGL API calls made by the emulator rather than the calls you actually submitted.

The PowerVR SDK includes an OpenGL ES/EGL API recording tool called PVRTrace that has all of the functionality you're looking for. 
The PVRTrace recording libraries can be used to record applications using PVRVFrame on Windows and Linux. The SDK also includes recording libraries for Android and Linux devices.

PVRTraceGUI (analysis tool for Windows, OSX & Linux) can be used to review and inspect the data you've recorded. It also has an Image Analysis widget that allows you to step through the draw calls in your recording & some other handy features, such as a Pixel Analysis pie chart that highlights the most costly fragment shaders in your render so you know where to focus shader optimisation.

There's also a PVRTrace standalone playback tool that allows you to replay your recordings on any of the supported OS's (inc. Windows & Android).

You can find an overview of the tool on the Imagination website [here](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/pvrtrace.asp) & can download PVRTrace through the PowerVR SDK installer, available [here](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I routinely debug OpenGL ES on Windows using the PowerVR VFrame translator, which converts OpenGL ES calls to OpenGL, as you said. I think it's the best solution.  VFrame has some step and tracing features, but mostly I am using the debugging features of MSVC++.

If you are using GLSurfaceView on android, it has an OpenGL ES tracing feature too.  I also recommend using an X86 AVD rather than ARM or trusting the drivers on any one device.  This article explains in detail:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1